# Converting a nested for loop into LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a following object structure

a Group has Many Teams and a Team has many Players

`m_Groups` is an observable collection of groups

I'm trying to get the Team name given a group name and a players name 
I can do this like in for each, but having trouble converting it to LINQ:

```
Dim retVal As String = String.empty  

For Each g In m_Groups
  For Each t In g.Teams
    For Each p In t.Players
      If p.PlayerName.Equals(name) Then
        retVal = t.TeamName
      End If
    Next
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obviously several ways of doing it, here is what came to my mind

```
  var team = m_Groups
       .SelectMany(g=>g.Teams)
       .FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Players.Any(p=>p.PlayerName == name));
```

I hope you'll be able to convert it to VB yourself

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim teamName = (From group in Groups _
                From team In group.Teams _
                From player In team.Players _
                Where player.PlayerName.Equals(name) _
                Select team.TeamName).FirstOrDefault()
```

(Disclaimer: I'm mostly guessing the VB syntax above.)

Also, my actual way of dealing with situations like youre would be to give players a `Team` property and connect them up once after loading instead of doing a lookup every time. (Assuming the player assignments don't change, a bidirectional connection would require some boilerplate to maintain.)

Answer (score 1):

With your setup, I am assuming you would perform a LINQ query every time you need to search for a particular team. A better approach would be to have a linear structure, such as a dictionary, which has `name` as a key.

Keeping close to what you got there, here is some code to play with:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1
  Class MyGroup
    Public Teams As New List(Of MyTeam)
  End Class
  Class MyTeam
    Public Players As New List(Of MyPlayer)
    Public TeamName As String
  End Class
  Class MyPlayer
    Public PlayerName As String
  End Class

  Dim m_Groups As New List(Of MyGroup)

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim p As New MyPlayer With {.PlayerName = "Player"}
    Dim t As New MyTeam With {.TeamName = "Team", .Players = New List(Of MyPlayer)({p})}
    m_Groups.Add(New MyGroup With {.Teams = New List(Of MyTeam)({t})})
    Dim name As String = "Player" 'player name to be searched

    Dim teamName = (From group In m_Groups _
                    From team In group.Teams _
                    From player In team.Players _
                    Where player.PlayerName.Equals(name) _
                    Select team.TeamName).FirstOrDefault()
  End Sub
End Class
```

It was heavily influenced by @millimoose's answer, with two slight changes:

1. `Dim team` -> `Dim teamName`, you cannot have two `team` variables in the same scope.
2. OP wants the team name, so `Select player` became `Select team.TeamName`.